# Unable to open password protected xlsx file generated from Apache Poi using Excel tool

Tags: excel, apache-poi, password-protection, fileopendialog

I have generated an xlsx password protected file using Apache POI framework, below added my code. however, Im unable to open the generated file using Excel tool. I am able to open it using Plan Maker free tool. any advises are welcome.

I have below jars used, commons-collections4-4.4.jar, commons-compress-1.20.jar, commons-math3-3.0.jar, poi-4.1.2.jar, poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar, SparseBitSet-1.1.jar, xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar

```
package com.pega.gcs.createworkbook;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.crypto.Biff8EncryptionKey;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ProtectedExcelFile {

    public static void main(final String... args) throws Exception {

        String fname = "FromJavaSecure1.xlsx";
        String label="Sheet1-Abc";  
        String cellvalue="Cell1";  

        org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet     sheet;  
        org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow       row;  
        org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell      cell;

        org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet     hsheet;  
        org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow       hrow;  
        org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell      hcell;

        FileInputStream fileInput = null;
        BufferedInputStream bufferInput = null;
        POIFSFileSystem poiFileSystem = null;
        FileOutputStream fileOut = null;

        try {


            try(

                    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
               ) 
            {
                     hsheet=workbook.createSheet(label); hrow=hsheet.createRow(0);
                     hcell=hrow.createCell(0); hcell.setCellValue(cellvalue);

         Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword("secret");

             fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fname);
         workbook.writeProtectWorkbook(Biff8EncryptionKey.getCurrentUserPassword(), "");

            workbook.write(fileOut);
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            /*
             * try {
             * 
             * bufferInput.close(); } catch (IOException ex) {
             * 
             * System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); }
             * 
             * try {
             * 
             * fileOut.close(); } catch (IOException ex) {
             * 
             * System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); }
             */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with XSSF and a `.xlsx` file? See https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html for code snippet needed

Comment: Try `String fname = "FromJavaSecure1.xls";` instead of `String fname = "FromJavaSecure1.xlsx";`. As you are ceating a `HSSFWorkbook`, which is in binrary `BIFF` file format, this **cannot** be named `*.xlsx`. Only `XSSFWorkbook`, which is in the `Office Open XML` file format, must be named `*.xlsx`.

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr, poi encryption.html page have good examples. I have managed to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter,  actually i tried both extensions xls and xlsx. I used XSSFWorkbook itself. anyways, Im posting below my working code.

Answer (score 1):

After referring to https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html , manage to get below code working for my requirement.

```
   /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package excelpasswordgeneration;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageAccess;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionMode;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.Encryptor;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

/**
 *
 * @author venu
 */
public class ExcelPasswordGeneration {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try (POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem()) {
            EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);
            // EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile, CipherAlgorithm.aes192, HashAlgorithm.sha384, -1, -1, null);
            Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
            enc.confirmPassword("foobaa");



            String label = "Sheet1-Raja";
            String cellvalue = "Cell1";

            org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet sheet;
            org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow row;
            org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell cell;
            try (
                    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
                sheet = workbook.createSheet(label);
                row = sheet.createRow(0);
                cell = row.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue(cellvalue);
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                workbook.write(out);


               // Read in an existing OOXML file and write to encrypted output stream
            // don't forget to close the output stream otherwise the padding bytes aren't added
            try (OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
                    OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs)) {
                opc.save(os);
            }
            // Write out the encrypted version
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("sample-encrypted.xlsx")) {
                fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
            }

            }

        }
    }

}
```